Flexdashboard in R Markdown: Plotly Plots Get Cut Off Inside Tabset on Grid Layout
I am trying to use the grid layout to create a flexdashboard. I would like to use tabsets in one of the grid sections to display multiple plots. However, when I do this, it seems that the tabs take up some of the available space, and the plots are not fully visible. Is there a way to fix this using custom CSS?
---
title: "Prueba Tabs"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
require(shinydashboard)
require(shiny)
require(plotly)
```

Row
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Gráfico A

```{r}
plot_ly(data = cars, x = ~speed, y = ~dist, mode = "markers")
```

### Gráfico B 

```{r}
plot_ly(data = mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~hp, type = "scatter", mode = "markers")
```
Row
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Gráfico C

```{r}
plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Sepal.Width, color = ~Species, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers')
```

### Gráfico D

```{r}
tabsetPanel(
  tabPanel("Gráfico 1", {
    plot_ly(data = cars, x = ~speed, y = ~dist, mode = "markers")
  }),
  tabPanel("Gráfico 2", {
    plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Sepal.Width, color = ~Species, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers')
  }),
  tabPanel("Gráfico 3", {
    plot_ly(data = mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~hp, type = "scatter", mode = "markers")
  })
)
```

Thank you!
